# ToggleButton on_state programmatically?

Tags: kivy, togglebutton

I'm making ToggleButtons programmatically and I want to set the on_state method, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
 tbutton = uix.togglebutton.ToggleButton(multiline=True,markup=True,text=text,group="g",size_hint=(1,None))
 tbutton.bind(on_state=self.my_function)
 def my_function(self,*args):
     print "TEST"
```

If I press the button nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You should bind **state** - not **on_state** ...

```
tbutton.bind(state=self.my_function)
```

That it *:)*

Comment: Thanks found it out after I made a dirty workaround, sometimes kivy can be very confusing. Especially because you bind on_press and on_release exactly as I did